# SQL: Combining three tables using JOIN and UNION

Tags: sql-server, join

In a rental management database I have three tables, one containing my article stock, one for the bookings of those articles and one storing all projects:

**stock**

```
IdStockType     Number     Caption     Inventory
1               100001     Monitor     10
2               100002     Keyboard    25
3               100003     Notebook    05
4               100004     Desktop     07
```

**bookings**

```
id     IdStockType     RentalPrice     Factor     Project
1      2               15              5          1
2      2               03              2          2
3      4               90              3          2
```

**projects**

```
id     Caption          startDate     endDate
1      Festival 2019    2019-03-01    2019-03-05
2      Kick-Off ABC     2019-04-15    2019-04-17
3      Big Conference   2019-04-16    2019-04-16
```

Now I want to write a query giving me the whole stock with information about bookings and project. If an article was not rented, it should be listed anyway. If it was rented, it should only be listed with the booking & project information. So it can be there multiple times:

```
IdStockType       Number       Factor       Inventory       Article       RentalPrice       Project
1                 100001       (NULL)       10              Monitor       (NULL)            (NULL)
2                 100002       5            25              Keyboard      15                Festival 2019
2                 100002       2            25              Keyboard      03                Kick-Off ABC
3                 100003       (NULL)       05              Notebook      (NULL)            (NULL)
4                 100004       3            07              Desktop       90                Kick-Off ABC
```

Now I have problem with my query:

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT 
    p.IdStockType,
    p.Number,
    o.Factor,
    p.Inventory,
    p.Caption AS Article,   
    q.Caption AS Project

FROM
    stock p,
    bookings o,
    projects q

WHERE
    p.IdStockType = o.IdStockType AND
    o.Project = q.id

    ) AS u

 RIGHT JOIN (SELECT     
    r.IdStockType,
    r.Number,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    r.Caption AS Article,
    NULL

 FROM
    stock r) d ON d.IdStockType = u.IdStockType;
```

The resulting amount of outputted lines seems to be correct, but the combination of the information is weird because the concordant columns are added as new ones.

Can anybody help me with the query?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Lars

Comment: Tip of the day: Switch to modern join syntax, which is the de facto standard now, and _never_ put commas in your `FROM` clause.

Comment: @Gardinero I have added a script below, please let me know if this satisfies your requirement

Comment: Learn to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: @Eric this type of comment is not necessary. Help is being asked for, why no show the way instead of demeaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from Stock stock
    left join (
        select 
                    * 
            from
                    Bookings bookings
                join Projects projects
                    on bookings.Project = projects.Id
        ) bookingProjects on stock.IdStockType = bookingProjects.IdStockType
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly, what I was looking for.